# Probability of a tail event without independence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $(\mathcal{F_n})_n$ a sequence of sub σ-algebras of $\mathcal{F},$ and $(u_r)_r$ a sequence of nonnegative real numbers which converges to 0. We suppose that :
$$\forall r \in \mathbb{N},\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\forall K \in \sigma(\mathcal{F_i,i \leq n}), \forall Q \in \sigma(\mathcal{F_i},i>n+r),|P(K \cap Q)-P(K)P(Q)|\leq u_r.$$

Prove that for every tail event K of $\mathcal{F_n},$ $P(K)=$ 0 or 1.

The result looks like Kolmogorov 0-1 law, but $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ is not independent. If we take a tail event K, we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},K\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_i, i \geq n).$ I tried to prove that $P(K)(1-P(K))=0$, can you give me a hint to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\epsilon >0$ we can find $n$ and $H \in \sigma(\mathcal F_i,i\leq n)$ such that $P(H\Delta K) <\epsilon$. [Because the unions of $\sigma(\mathcal F_i,i\leq n)$ form an algebra which generates $\sigma(\mathcal F_{\infty})$ and $K$ is measurable w.r.t. this sigma algebra]. Now we get $|P(K\cap H) -P(H)P(K)| <u_r$ for every $r$ since $K$ is in the tail sigma algebra. Thus we have $P(H\Delta K) <\epsilon$ and $P(K\cap H) =P(H)P(K)$ from which it follows easily that $P(K)=0$ or $1$.

Comment: I didn't understand the existence of $H$ such that $P(H \Delta K)<\epsilon$

Comment: That is the basic Approximation Theorem of measure Theory. (A proof can be found in Halmos's book). If $K$ is in the  sigma algebra generated by an algebra and $\epsilon >0$ the there exist $H$ in the algebra such that $P(H\Delta K) <\epsilon$. @fredwagner